nano command execution stuck
In nano v8.0 there's an option to send selection to X clipboard in the nanorc:
"{execute}|xsel -ib{enter}{undo}"

which does perfectly.
I tried using xclip utility instead:
"{execute}|xclip -sel c{enter}{undo}"

The result was an infinite execution [ Executing... ], insensitive to interaction until hit ^C. After the cancelling it appeared done the copying, no errors, but what's with the stuckage? Why does it happen and is there a fix?
I'm on Kubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa).

Do you get the same when running e.g. echo foo | xclip -sel c in the terminal? There's a -verbose option you can add to xclip which maybe can provide some insights as to what's causing the stuckage.

@kos No, xclip works fine. It would get stuck if there's no stdin and no file, but if at least one it works.

Why?
From this answer:

Selections in X work by two X clients cooperating: One X client claims it has a selection (primary, secondary, clipboard), and another X client that wants to paste the selection contacts the first client to receive it.

In your case the original xclip exits but its child survives to claim it has a selection and to serve for future clients that want to paste. Usually (e.g. in case of printf foo | xclip -sel c) you don't notice the child because it's in the background.
With xsel the mechanism is the same: a child survives in the background.
The difference is the child xsel is smart and redirects its stdin and stdout to /dev/null, its stderr to a log. The child xclip is not that smart, it keeps "using" the standard streams inherited from the the original xclip; it does not really use them, it just keeps them open.
In the [ Executing... ] state nano is waiting for the output of the invoked command. The command is a writer and nano is a reader of some pipe.  If any process keeps the pipe open for writing then nano will keep waiting for further output. In case of xclip the child keeps the pipe open and thus prevents nano from continuing*. In case of xsel the child does not keep the pipe open.
Your problem is very similar to this one: ssh command doesn't terminate.

* Trivia: copying from elsewhere, i.e. making some other process claim it has a selection, will make the child xclip exit; this will unblock nano.

Fix
Forcing a child to close its inherited standard streams without affecting the parent first is not easy in general, I think. Luckily here you don't really need nano to capture any output from xclip (no matter if from the parent or from the child). Redirecting output from the parent xclip to /dev/null is enough to fix the problem. In my tests the standard shell syntax works:
"{execute}|xclip -sel c >/dev/null 2>&1{enter}{undo}"


Exhaustive answer, thanks a lot. Liked the trivia, indeed so.
